Plotly plot does not render in viewer pane
Trying to use plotl_ly() in Rstudio and it refuses to render in the viewer pane as expected.
Tried uninstalling plotly, R and Rstudio and the problem persists. Anyone else have the same problem?
Tried running a minimal example like so and I get a white screen in my viewer pane instead of a plot.
library(plotly)

plot_ly(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)

Here is my session info:
R version 4.4.0 (2024-04-24 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64
Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22631)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.utf8    LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=English_Canada.utf8    

time zone: America/Toronto
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] plotly_4.10.4 ggplot2_3.5.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] vctrs_0.6.5       httr_1.4.7        cli_3.6.2         rlang_1.1.3       purrr_1.0.2      
 [6] generics_0.1.3    jsonlite_1.8.8    data.table_1.15.4 glue_1.7.0        colorspace_2.1-0 
[11] htmltools_0.5.8.1 scales_1.3.0      fansi_1.0.6       grid_4.4.0        crosstalk_1.2.1  
[16] munsell_0.5.1     tibble_3.2.1      fastmap_1.1.1     yaml_2.3.8        lifecycle_1.0.4  
[21] compiler_4.4.0    dplyr_1.1.4       htmlwidgets_1.6.4 pkgconfig_2.0.3   tidyr_1.3.1      
[26] rstudioapi_0.16.0 digest_0.6.35     viridisLite_0.4.2 R6_2.5.1          tidyselect_1.2.1 
[31] utf8_1.2.4        pillar_1.9.0      magrittr_2.0.3    withr_3.0.0       tools_4.4.0      
[36] gtable_0.3.5      lazyeval_0.2.2   


Recently happened to me also. Tried all the fixes on SO to no avail. It breaks all the time, and it was working in 4.3.2, but not 4.4.0. There is a workaround: click the "Show in new window" icon on the Viewer Pane header and your plot will render in your default browser. Or roll back to 4.3.2.

This issue has been recently fixed, happens in RStudio when using R version 4.4.0 with all  plot and HTML objects. See the issue here. Looks like issue is fixed by installing patched build

Thank you! I had no idea R v4.4.0 had a patch for this issue, hopefully this post boosts awareness for others going through similar issues. Downloaded the patch, opened R, changed R version in global options to point at it and problem solved. Thank you again!

User @sactyr's comment

This issue has been recently fixed, happens in RStudio when using R version 4.4.0 with all plot and HTML objects. See the issue here. Looks like issue is fixed by installing patched build.

solved my issue. Installing the unofficial patched build brings back plotly to the viewer pane. Seems like the issue is indeed related to R version 4.4.0.
