Plot_ly graphs in R not showing
I use R version 4.4.0 (2024-04-24 ucrt) -- "Puppy Cup" on Windows with RStudio 2024.04.0 Build 735.
When I'm plotting with the base R function, i.e.
plot(rnorm(50), rnorm(50))

everything works fine, the plot is shown in the plot panel. When I'm using plot_ly() (plotly package version 4.10.4), i.e.
library(plotly)
y <- rnorm(100, mean = 1)
x <- c(1:100)
data <- data.frame(x, y)
plot_ly(data, x = ~x, y = ~y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers')

no plot is shown at all. I don't get an error message, the view panel just remains empty/blank white. First I thought it might be because I have too many data points (around 140,000 in the original dataset), but it is not even working with this minimal example given above. dev.off() doesn't work either. Any suggestions?

This is a known issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78469951/plotly-plot-does-not-render-in-viewer-pane for a fix.

Try to change the size of the plot panel, it worked for me

Thanks Stefan and Anisa! :) It works now
